# When to initialise viewController global variables using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I come from an Objective C background and I'm normally used to declaring my properties (global variables to the class) inside the init method of a given class i.e. something like this:

```
-(instancetype) init {
   self = [super init];
   if(self){
      self.viewModel = [[MyViewModel alloc] init:self];
   }
   return self;
}
```

When self.viewModel is a property and I normally pass the a view controller as a parameter to the view model for callback purposes. I'm currently trying to do the same in swift.

I have a normal a custom view controller class, with the following init method:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.viewModel = SearchViewModel(callback: self)
    }
```

Now with the code above, xcode complains that

> self.viewModel has not been initialised

However when I try initialise the viewModel i.e:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        self.viewModel = SearchViewModel(callback: self)
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
```

I then get

> self used before super.init call

How would I sort this out in Swift?

Comment: Try using the `viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: To do that I would have to initialise the viewModel in the init method and then write a setter method to set the callback to the viewModel in the viewDidLoad method. Is this really the only solution?

Comment: You could / should declare `viewModel` to be of type `SearchViewModel!` for example and use the first code alternative.

Comment: luk2302 this makes the code work. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: `Swift` initializers want all properties of `self` to be set up properly / to have a value before calling a super initializer.

Second off: You mustn't use `self` before the `super.init`-call because otherwise the properties that you would set in the super constructor are not yet set meaning whoever *receives* the non-finished `self`-instance can not be sure about the state of `self`.

Solution: Make `viewModel` of type `SearchViewModel!` and use the first code alternative.

Explanation: By making `viewModel` an implicitly unwrapped optional it implicitly contains `nil` in the beginning, therefore you can now call `super.init` and set an *actual*  value to `viewModel` after that.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written will never compile in Swift. The reason is that you can't pass `self` to `SearchViewModel` until `self` is fully initialized (i.e. has a value for all of its non-nil properties), but you can't fully initialize `self` without giving it a view model.

This is most likely a reference cycle, and you'll leak memory.

To fix this, make either the `callback` property of `SearchViewModel` optional, or the the viewModel property of your view controller optional. This permits you to fully initialize either without providing a reference until after the object is fully initialized, and allows you to make the reference weak, thereby preventing the reference cycle.

So you'd write `weak var viewModel: SearchViewModel?`, or `weak var viewModel: SearchViewModel!`, if you believe that `SearchViewModel` will never be `nil` when you dereference it, and are willing to run the risk of crashing.